# MySQL 5.5 utf8 trouble

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I've done all the things that worked on previous versions of MySQL (and new to MySQL 5.5) to set utf8 encoding.
Now I have output of

```
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
```

exactly what I wanted:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

And that cmds in [mysqld]:

```
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

In [client] and [mysql]:

```
default-character-set= utf8
```

But default table encoding in creating is still latin1!
Am I missed some other things with MySQL 5.5 to make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default table encoding equals to the current database encoding.

You can check it with

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE dbname;
```

PS: it's a good practice to **always** specify encoding explicitly. That way you won't rely on server settings.

Comment: That's the stipidest thing I forget about! Troubles with that special version of MySQL make me forget the basics. Thank you, Ivan!